# Array not outputting properly

Tags: java, arrays

In an attempt to create a program that displays a set of inputted arrays backwards, I came across a problem where no matter what I do, all the variables output as "0". This probably has some simple issue to do with the loop I'm using to get the arrays set, and something that I've overlooked, I just need a fresh pair of eyes to tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
import java.io.*;
class ReverseArray
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String inInput;
        int count = 0;
        int[] userInput = new int[10];
        int newInput = 0;


        System.out.println ("Please enter ten whole numbers:");

        for (count = 0; count <= 9; count++) 
        {
            inInput = reader.readLine();
            newInput = Integer.parseInt(inInput);
            newInput = userInput[count];
        }

        System.out.println ("These numbers in reverse order is:");
        System.out.println (userInput[9]);
        System.out.println (userInput[8]);
        System.out.println (userInput[7]);
        System.out.println (userInput[6]);
        System.out.println (userInput[5]);
        System.out.println (userInput[4]);
        System.out.println (userInput[3]);
        System.out.println (userInput[2]);
        System.out.println (userInput[1]);
        System.out.println (userInput[0]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
userInput[count] = newInput;
```

not

```
newInput = userInput[count];
```

Answer (score 2):

The statement `newInput = userInput[count];` assigns the value of the right-hand side of the statement, i.e. the array element at index `count`, to the variable `newInput`. You want to do the reverse:

```
userInput[count] = newInput;   // assign the value of newInput to array element
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newInput = userInput[count];
```

Should instead read:

```
userInput[count] = newInput;
```

Or for more context, your assignment loop:

```
for (count = 0; count <= 9; count++) {
    inInput = reader.readLine();
    newInput = Integer.parseInt(inInput); 
    newInput = userInput[count]; 
}
```

Should read:

```
for (count = 0; count <= 9; count++) {
    inInput = reader.readLine();
    newInput = Integer.parseInt(inInput); 
    userInput[count] = newInput;
}
```

You are assigning the array to `newInput` instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

`newInput = userInput[count];`

needs to be

`userInput[count] = newInput;`

but you can probably skip unnecessary assignment with

`userInput[count] = Integer.parseInt(inInput);`

Answer (score 0):

On the line where you have

`newInput = userInput[count];`

reverse these two variables should be

`userInput[count] = newInput;`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to reverse this line:

```
userInput[count] = newInput;
```

However, use the `for-loop` to print-out results and the `.length` to calculate the array length:

```
import java.io.*;

class ReverseArray
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        int[] userInput = new int[10];

        // fill the array
        System.out.println ("Please enter ten whole numbers:");
        for (int count = 0; count < userInput.length; count++)
            userInput[count] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        // print out the array values
        System.out.println ("These numbers in reverse order is:");
        for (int count = userInput.length - 1; count >= 0; count--)
            System.out.println (userInput[count]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't assigned any value to your array,

`newInput = userInput[count];`

Change this to

`userInput[count] = newInput;`